# How to discover network services on domain other than .local domain in Android?

Tags: android, zeroconf, avahi, network-service, android-nsd

I want to use Android Network Service Discovery (NSD) function to discover some local network services advertised on local domain. I read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) on Android website about Android NSD. I can find the network services advertised on .local domain without problem. But I have some other network services that are advertised not directly on .local domain, but on a domain like `mydevice.mycompany.local`. In the Android NSD API example, there is a function to discover the service with given service type ("_http._tcp."), protocol, and listener:

```
discoverServices("_http._tcp.", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
```

This by default only discovers the network service on `.local` domain, not on the other local domain like my case `mydevice.mycompany.local`. However, I installed a Bonjour app on Android and it can find the other domain services. So I think there is a way to get those network services by code.

I browsed through Android NSD API and didn't find an option to let me specify the domain name from which I want to discover services. So how can I use Android NSD code to discover the local network services on a domain like that?

Comment: Generally speaking this is not supported by the Multicast DNS specification.  It specifically requires that you use the hostname .local.

You can however use the same kind of DNS-SD records (e.g. service._http._tcp) in normal "unicast" DNS.  This is what the Bonjour app will be dong, sadly I have no idea what Android API (if any) will do this for you.